# iOS: Geofence is not working with 2g or 3g internet connectivity

Tags: iphone, wifi, monitoring, regions, geofencing

I am facing critical situation with geofence in my iOS App.

It is working fine with wifi but when i set Network access point to 2g or 3g it will stop working unexpectedly.

So below are my queries:

- How geofence is working with 2g or 3g internet.
- is there any demo which used 2g or 3g internet for iOS Application.
- These delegate methods are not working properly when internet is accessed by 2g or 3g net.

delegate methods are :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

so what should i need to do for calling of region monitoring delegate methods?

Thanks in advance.